# using post meta data as permalink tags

Tags: permalinks

I have a client who would like their wordpress permalinks to look like this:

```
 /%category%/%state%/%city%/%street%/
```

I can get this information easily enough with custom meta data in the post editor, but I'm at a loss to see a method for creating custom permalink tags. Can anyone tell me how this might be achieved?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should take it from another angle and use Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types and http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

That will give you the permalink structure you want, and also provide a way to organize and enter the data from the admin side.